# API calls return JSON on my local machine but return HTML on Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, axios

I have a Discord bot that makes some API calls. When I run the bot from my computer, it all works fine, however when I push my code to Heroku (where I am hosting my bot) the API call returns this error:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: FetchError: invalid json response body at https://sky.shiiyu.moe/api/v2/profile/SirArchibald97 reason: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
2021-01-07T11:45:02.931529+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at /app/node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js:272:32
2021-01-07T11:45:02.931532+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
2021-01-07T11:45:02.931532+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at async Object.execute (/app/methods/link.js:93:20)
2021-01-07T11:45:02.931532+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at async Client.<anonymous> (/app/index.js:47:28)
2021-01-07T11:45:02.931832+00:00 app[worker.1]: (node:4) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
2021-01-07T11:45:02.931970+00:00 app[worker.1]: (node:4) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Edit: I am requesting two different APIs in my code, using the `node-fetch` npm module. This is the one which returns the error:

```js
let res = await fetch(`https://sky.shiiyu.moe/api/v2/profile/${player.displayname}`);
let data = await res.json();
```

And this is the one which works fine:

```js
let p_response = await fetch(`https://api.hypixel.net/player?key=${api_key}&name=${args[1]}`);
let { player } = await p_response.json();
```

Edit 2: I have switched from `node-fetch` to `axios` in the hope that it might work, and I am now recieving a 503 status error instead. Once again, it works fine on my machine, but returns the error when I deploy to Heroku. Here is the new code:

```js
const axios = require("axios");
let res = await axios.get(`https://sky.shiiyu.moe/api/v2/profile/${player.displayname}`);
let data = res.data;
```

Comment: `invalid json response body at https://sky.shiiyu.moe/api/v2/profile/SirArchibald97 reason: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`—it looks like you're getting HTML or XML or something instead of JSON. Take a look at the response without trying to parse it as JSON. It may be an error page or something. Also, check the HTTP response code you get.

Comment: I know it’s returning HTML, but I’m not sure why, as the request returns JSON when I run the bot from my system. I have logged the response to the console and it returns the same thing as the JSON but as one long string of text rather than an object.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] of an API request? Are you setting an accept header?

Comment: @Chris I have just edited my question to include the examples you wanted. And no, I am not sending an accept header as I am not entirely sure how.

Comment: have you checked which request headers are being set in both instances?

Comment: To set an accept header see the `accept` line in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29775797/fetch-post-json-data/29823632#29823632). The HTML you're receiving may be the 503 status page if it's behind something like Nginx or IIS.

Comment: I set an accept header and a content-type header (both to `applicaton/json`) but I am still getting the error

Comment: Are you authenticating somehow?

Comment: @Chris I am not sure what you mean by authenticating, I'm rather new to APIs.

Comment: Well, the API example you give that's working asks for an API key. The one that's failing doesn't. Are you authenticating some other way, e.g. with a bearer token? Or is this a public API that anybody is able to freely use, without limit?

Comment: @Chris No, the API that isn't working doesn't need a key to use.

Comment: Can you try to do the associated curl request from your computer and from your heroku server ? as heroku share some ip it might be simply an ip block/ban from the remote server

Comment: @Daphoque sorry, I'm quite new to this sort of stuff, I'm not sure what a curl request is?

Comment: curl is just an http requester, but if you don't know it we will do in another way. Can you display the raw text response receive from fetch/axios, with fetch: console.log(res.text()), with axios: res.headers['content-type']; console.log(res.data). Try to display the two if possible :)

Comment: do you have somewhere the code base to take a look?

Comment: Please check that request/response in your browser. What is the client sending and receiving? Can you post that here? Anyways: I always handle errors as a general rule of thumb. Look at this, the checked answer give you a pretty nice solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40370399/catching-errors-in-typescript-promises

Comment: You can easily check your requests and responses for example in Google Chrome. Just push F12 and open the Developer Tools and switch to the Network Tab. Then you'll click on the request to the https://sky.shiiyu.moe/api/v2/profile/ URL and look at differences in your local setup and the heroku setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the API you are using, using CURL.

`curl "https://sky.shiiyu.moe/api/v2/profile/SirArchibald97"`

```
HTTP/1.1 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable
Date: Sat, 16 Jan 2021 13:27:30 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: close
Set-Cookie: __cfduid=dfef31ed9a3326383a42315e646837f531610803650; expires=Mon, 15-Feb-21 13:27:30 GMT; path=/; domain=.shiiyu.moe; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax; Secure
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0, no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT
cf-request-id: 07acfa3991000041f79a8d8000000001
Expect-CT: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
Report-To: {"endpoints":[{"url":"https:\/\/a.nel.cloudflare.com\/report?s=DfiyBY1Zc4DC%2Bxzh2Ug61Brj2X5zQ4Ae5VlhYj8Ci7bRKlaJGGTO9PFZuXqXYyOEIiWKdM2n8ykJlwf3Y79zCUxIire2LUy%2BzAtDGAxqcg%3D%3D"}],"group":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
NEL: {"report_to":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
Server: cloudflare
CF-RAY: 61282ca2893341f7-MRS
```

I got an HTML response. It was `CloudFlare` protection. It is probably working in your local machine due to CloudFlare cookies.

This is a issue with the API configuration. You need to reach them and ask to whitelist you IP or you would have to use some sort of browser emulator like `selenium` to bypass CloudFlare firewall.

Comment: Ahh ok, thank you for figuring it out. I have been stuck with this issue for a while.

Comment: Great, glad to help.

Comment: Thanks @Abkarino for the direction. I’m facing a similar Cloudflare. It shows a captcha page when i do a GET reques to a website from Zapier. Quick question: By “you need to reach them” you mean whom? Cloudflare?

Comment: @AnupamChugh you need to contact whom setup cloudflare on the host. If it is automatic, they you should find a place to setup whitelist in your Heroku dashboard or contact Heroku customer support.
Zapier has an ip range which you are told to use for whitelisting.

Answer (score 0):

Sending request with default `axios` config works well, so your issue related to:

- axios config
- heroku config

```js
const player = { displayname: 'voice' };

const sendReq = async () => {
  let res = await axios.get(`https://sky.shiiyu.moe/api/v2/profile/${player.displayname}`);
  console.log(res.data)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.21.1/axios.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="sendReq()">Send request</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope the workaround here solves the issue [GET request returns index.html doc instead of json data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64496815/get-request-returns-index-html-doc-instead-of-json-data)

Let me know!